# How do I resolve a shore power ground fault on a bonded neutral generator?

Tags: electrical, generator, grounding-and-bonding

I have a 50A RV with a custom solar setup using a Victron 12v Multiplus II 2x120v inverter. In normal operation I run shore power through an EMS and the into the Multiplus, then from the Multiplus into the original OEM panel. Everything has been working flawlessly with the system since I installed it 1.5 years ago.

Recently I purchased a new Ford truck with a 2kw generator function "Pro Power Onboard". This was a significant feature, as I thought it would allow me to provide supplementary power to my system when the solar panels alone can't quite make it.

However, this generator system is set up in the truck with a bonded ground/neutral, and when plugged in as a shore power source for the RV immediately triggers a ground fault and does not function. I'm assuming this is because the trailer is also bonded at its panel and this creates a flow of power on the ground which should not be there.

A common fix suggested is to remove the ground wire connecting the truck, and just run a hot and neutral line into the trailer. However, I'm a bit uncomfortable with this solution, as it does not seem safe. But I don't really have the electrical knowledge to fully assess this one way or another.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can successful use this bonded neutral generator as a shore power source for my system?

Answer (score 2):

Your generator *should* have a bonded neutral and any quality shore power connection *will* have a bonded neutral.

I gather this is just your first time connecting to a GFCI protected circuit.

> I'm assuming this is because the trailer is also bonded at it's panel and this creates a flow of power on the ground which should not be there.

Why the bleep is your RV panel bonded? Every source it's likely to be plugged into will be bonded, so that's two bonds, which is one too many.

Probably as likely is that something in your RV has a ground fault.

Start plugging it into a GFCI protected outlet for your shore power.  If that does not work, that's your problem (not the truck) and troubleshoot it normally.

Answer (score 0):

When the RV is (120/240-volt) powered independently, either by operation of those Multiplus inverters or by an onboard generator, there should exist a ground-neutral bond *somewhere* in the RV. But when the RV receives power through its shore power cord, *there should be no ground-neutral bond in the RV!*

In other words the RV needs a switchable ground-neutral bond. The transfer switch is an obvious place to make/control this connection because the transfer switch "knows" when the RV is taking power via the shore power cord.